# Replicate function doesn't work with "on the fly" function

Tags: r

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 6, expr = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100), simplify = TRUE
  )
)
```

I want generate 50 `data.frame`s with this function:

```
f_1 <- function(x) {
  data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)))
}


lt_1 <- replicate(n = 50, expr = f_1(), simplify = FALSE)
```

The result is ok. But, when apply `f_1` within a function (*on the fly*), this function doesn't work:

```
lt_2 <- replicate(
  n = 50, expr = function(x) {
    data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)))
    }, simplify = FALSE
)
```

What's problem?

Comment: It works fine. You replicated the creation of that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can wrap it inside the `()` and call `()` to execute the function

```
lt_2 <- replicate(
   n = 50, expr = (function(x) {
     data.frame(x = replicate(n = 5, runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 100)))
       })(), simplify = FALSE
  )
```

---

In the OP's `lt_1`, the function is called with `f_1()`